# wordpress passing variables through permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, url, permalinks

I've been researching wordpress' passing php variables through permalinks topic, but still haven't found my solution yet.

I've got a page called:

```
    http://example.com/termekek/kategoriak/
```

and I would like to redirect through an a href like this:

```
    <a href="http://example.com/category.php?category=furdo">
```

to my category.php, where I could use the passed variable to do some mysql magic. And I'd also like it to be rewritten like this:

```
    http://example.com/termekek/kategoriak/furdo/
```

I've been trying for days now, looked up for rewrite rules, add_query_vars functions, but none of them seemed to work. Could you please help me? Thank you !

Comment: Is this even possible ?